# Angular Blank Screen When Publishing to .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried to publish my Angular 7 app to a .NET core Web API. First I ran

```
ng build --prod --base-href=./
```

After that I set up my Web API by adding this to `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllers();
endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
});
```

And then made a `Fallback.cs` Controller

```cs
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WEBAPI.Controllers
{
    public class Fallback : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
            "index.html"), "text/HTML");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my web api however, I get these errors in the console:

```
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:5000/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:10 GET http://localhost:5000/styles.8657acc07ecc1c533b68.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:5000/polyfills.e254f6b9bf511460eb6d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NotFound)
```

My `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.8657acc07ecc1c533b68.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.e254f6b9bf511460eb6d.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.e219b28daed7f1597f1c.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

It is located in a `wwwroot` folder.
I have tried changing `base href` to  , `/`, and have tried deleting the tag altogether, but none of that seems to be working for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use fallback routes, and a strange looking base href, a good approach for serving single page apps from asp.net core sites is to use the existing [SPA middleware](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501). The Angular template will include the spa dependencies and generate a Configure() method which looks something like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (!env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
  }

  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });

  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
      // or spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
  });
```

There are additional configurations in the Angular template (`dotnet new angular`) that will build the angular app in prod mode during a `dotnet publish` and copy the dist files to the appropriate location.